# Show that a subset in V is linearly independent if and only if the set of coordinate vectors is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

> Let $B$ be a basis of the vector space $V$. Show that a subset {**v**$_1$,
>   . . . , **v**$_p$} in *V* is linearly independent if and only if the set
>   of coordinate vectors {[**v**$_1]_B$, . . . , [**v**$_p]_B$} is linearly
>   independent in $\mathbb{R}$$^{n}$.

This is for a first course in Linear Algebra, so it's not expected (or supposed) to be the most intricate or drawn-out.

**Thoughts:** Is it safe to assume that there is a coordinate mapping **x** ↦ [**x**]$_B$ (since it does not explicitly state this) ? Then, I could use the fact that the coordinate mapping is one-to-one and linear to write out a couple of equations that have the same solutions.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe to assume this. This mapping is called *the standard representation of $\{v_1,...,v_p\}$ with respect to B*. It's an isomorphism so linear indepenence will be preserved.
However, it's simpler to just write out what it means for a subset of $V$ to be linearly independent and carry through